# Remove Order ID Prefix — Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce via GTM

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, google-tag-manager

I have an issue with some inconsistencies in the data passing through to Google Analytics (GA).

I'm sending Shopify purchase event data to GTM formatted as per the Enhanced Ecommerce docs [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce). While I can confirm my Order IDs do not have any prefix, eg.. simply `12345`, some records populated on GA include a `#` prefix while others do not.

I'm wondering if there are any settings or quirks with GA configuration that could be leading to this inconsistent behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Search and Replace filter to apply to the View where you define a rule based on your pagePath where the orderid is present.

Comment: Thanks for noting this. While helpful, I'm really hoping to strip out the # from all records entirely.